# How to properly use module augmentation to extend an existing TypeScript library?

Tags: typescript

I am wanting to write up my first TypeScript declaration file by hand in order to 1) add typings to a small library that currently has none and 2) Give myself a better understanding of how TS and declaration files work.

In my application code I wanted to use [this](https://github.com/jpoon/winston-azuretable) `winston-transport` called `winston-azuretable`. I looked for a `@types` npm package to go with it but there was none so I decided it would be a great learning experience to create my own.  I added a `types` folder, set my `tsconfig.json` to look for types in that `types` folder and I was able to get it working like this:

**types/index.d.ts**

```
declare module "winston-azuretable" {
    import * as winston from "winston";
    import * as Transport from "winston-transport";

    export interface AzureTableOptions extends Transport.TransportStreamOptions {
        useDevStorage?: boolean;
        account?: string;
        key?: string;
        tableName?: string;
        partitionKey?: string;
        nestedMeta?: boolean;
    }

    export interface AzureLoggerInstance extends Transport {
        log?(info: any, next: () => void): void;

        log?(level: string | object, msg: string, meta: object, callback: (err: Error, inserted: boolean) => void): void;
        log?(level: string | object, msg: string, callback: (err: Error, inserted: boolean) => void): void;

        query(options: winston.QueryOptions, callback: (err: Error, results: any) => void): void;
        query(callback: (err: Error, results: any) => void): void;

        new(options?: AzureTableOptions): AzureLoggerInstance;
    }

    export const AzureLogger: AzureLoggerInstance;
}
```

Then I could consume it like this

```
import winston from "winston";
import * as winstonAzureTable from "winston-azuretable";

export default winston.createLogger({
  levels: winston.config.syslog.levels,
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.colorize(),
        winston.format.label({ label: "[sandbox]" }),
        winston.format.timestamp({ format: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss" }),
        winston.format.printf((e) => `${e.level}: ${e.label} ${e.timestamp} ${e.message}`)
      ),
      level: "debug"
    }),
    new winstonAzureTable.AzureLogger({
      account: "test",
      key: "test",
      level: "info",
      partitionKey: "foo",
      tableName: "sandbox",
      useDevStorage: false
    })
  ]
});
```

So far this was great, but I noticed that other `winston` transports were able to appear like an extension of the `winston` library which would mean I should be able to do something like `new winston.transports.AzureLogger(...)`

Any example of that would be this `winston-dynamodb` transport [here](https://github.com/inspiredjw/winston-dynamodb/blob/master/lib/winston-dynamodb.d.ts) so I updated my code to do exactly what this library does, but I still cannot get either my transport or the `winston-dynamodb` transport to show up under `winston.transports`.

Can someone explain what the purpose of this code is if it doesn't allow me to use the custom transport in the `winston.transports` namespace?

```
declare module "winston" {
    interface Transports {
        DynamoDB: DynamoDB;
    }
}
```

Comment: A tangent question I had as well is what is the conventional way to create a declaration file like this? I tried looking at the docs on the TypeScript website, but I seem to see all kinds of different ways libraries are doing it in practice that all seem to differ from each other as well as the documentation. Questions like "Do I use `declare module "module-name" { ... }` in my `*.d.ts` files or do you keep the file completely flat? Does it really make a difference?